# Why do divs that are direct children of body fill it's width? And how can you prevent it?

Tags: html, css

Why do divs fill the body width when they are direct children of body?

This may be a simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer. Perhaps because of the overwhelming number of questions and tutorials on the opposite (getting a div to fill an area).

Here is a Fiddle to demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/xr9mc8n5/

```
<head>
    <style>
        #container { background-color: #ffcc99; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        CONTENT
    </div>
</body>
```

The div needs to size itself to it's content, and cannot have a fixed px or % width. Please don't give answers using JavaScript, I need a pure CSS solution.

Perhaps I'm forgetting something fundamental, but everything I've tried has had no effect. Any assistance and insight is appreciated!

Comment: so setting display: inline-block; doesn't do what you want?

Comment: They fill the width because they are by default display block, you can change it to display inline and the width will be based on it's content but it's hard to tell what exactly you are looking for by the description in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `display` styling of a div is `block`.

You could use `display:inline` or use a `span` tag instead, which would result in the div/span only covering the width that is "needed".

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the inherent nature of the CSS **[Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html)** and, specifically, the property `display: block;`, which is the inherent display value for the `<div>` element.

To fix it, simply set your div to `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`. This will cause your div to only be as wide as its content.

Answer (score -1):

Divs are block level elements so they take up a complete line in the document. By default they fill their container. you will have to set an additional container. The additional container will need to be set to inline instead of block. the div with class of red still gives you overall control of the outside of the growing div.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/d4hzujfq/

```
<body>
<div class="red"> 
    <div class="inline blue">Content when you add more it grows</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Ed

Comment: the whole question was about a div directly a child of body